# Wine crash after installing a windows app

Tags: installed-programs

I am a Dj and trying to load Traktor Scratch Pro2 and its drivers onto Ubuntu 16.4 through wine. I can get the program installed but then I try to open the app it give a crash report. I really need this to work so I can plug up my interface and make my music. Can anyone help with the install and execution?

Comment: Does the crash routine offer an opportunity to select and copy technical details? If so, please share those details. In the meantime I'm glancing at old bugs such as [Traktor Scratch Pro 1.2.4 crashes on startup](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21916) (a duplicate) and [Traktor Scratch Pro: page fault on write access](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26219) (abandoned).

Comment: I uninstalled Traktor 2 and reinstalled it and now I right click on the icon, open with is not an option. Once pressed there is no reaction

Comment: my biggest issue is that I am still very new to uBuntu and installing through wine has not been easy every program loaded through wine has crashed when attempting to open it after installation. I have removed Wine and all of its accessories completely or to the best of my knowledge and reinstalled wine repeatedly thinking I did something wrong. This last time I just left it and thought it could be traktor so I'm really out of options because now the crash report does not even show up.